# How to draw iso-regular graphs

Tags: diagrams, asymptote

I want to draw the diagram given below :

[image]

I am able to do this much :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
￼\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5] 
\GraphInit[vstyle=Art] 
\SetGraphArtColor{red}{olive} 
\grPetersen[form=1,RA=5,RB=3]%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is I am able to draw:

[image]

**Question :** With the help of above code I am able to draw point , but I want to draw four points in a square form and edges between them, see the diagram above.

Comment: There's no question in your post. Please only ask (_specific_) questions about problems you encounter / what doesn't work.

Comment: @ magula I have edited the question

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! One document class is enough…

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Check out an alternative approach with `Asymptote`:

[image]

```
%          qgr.tex
% run as
%
% pdflatex qgr.tex
% asy qgr-*.asy
% pdflatex qgr.tex
%
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
struct QuadGraph{
    pair a,b,c,d;
    pair center;
    guide s;
    real startNo;
    pen linePen, dotPen, idPen;
    void operator init(pair a,pair b,pair c,pair d){
        this.a=a; this.b=b; this.c=c; this.d=d; 
        center=(a+b+c+d)/4;
    }
    void draw(pen p=linePen){
        draw(s,p);
    }
    void dot(pen p=dotPen){
        dot(s,p,UnFill);
    }
    void label(pen p=idPen){
        label("$"+string(startNo)+"$",  a,1.5*unit(a-center),p);
        label("$"+string(startNo+1)+"$",b,1.5*unit(b-center),p);
        label("$"+string(startNo+2)+"$",c,1.5*unit(c-center),p);
        label("$"+string(startNo+3)+"$",d,1.5*unit(d-center),p);
    }

    void operator init(pair center, real side, real startNo
    ,pen linePen=currentpen, pen dotPen=currentpen, pen idPen=currentpen){
        this.center=center;
        this.startNo=startNo;
        this.linePen=linePen;
        this.dotPen=dotPen;
        this.idPen=idPen;
        a=center+( side/2, side/2);
        b=center+(-side/2, side/2);
        c=center+(-side/2,-side/2);
        d=center+( side/2,-side/2);
        s=a--b--c--d--cycle;
    }
}

QuadGraph operator*(transform tr, QuadGraph s){
    s.a=tr*s.a; s.b=tr*s.b; s.c=tr*s.c; s.d=tr*s.d;
    s.s=tr*s.s;
    s.center=tr*s.center;
    return s;
}

void joinOut(QuadGraph u, QuadGraph v, pen p=u.linePen){
    draw(u.b--v.a,p);
} 
void joinIn(QuadGraph u, QuadGraph v, pen p=u.linePen){
    draw(u.c--v.d,p);
} 

struct cycloQuad{
    int n;
    QuadGraph[] s;
    real side, R;
    pen linePen, dotPen, idPen;

    void makeCycle(){
        s=new QuadGraph[]; 
        pair u=(0,R);
        real phi;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
            phi=i*360/n;
            s[i]=rotate(phi)*QuadGraph(u,side,startNo=i*4+1,linePen=linePen,dotPen=dotPen,idPen=idPen);
            s[i].draw();
        }
    }

    void draw(){
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
            joinOut(s[i],s[(i+1)%n]);
            joinIn (s[i],s[(i+2)%n]);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
            s[i].dot();
            s[i].label();
        }
    }

    void operator init(int n=5, real side=1, real R=12
    ,pen linePen=currentpen, pen dotPen=currentpen, pen idPen=currentpen
        ){
            assert(n>2 && side>0 && R>0);
            this.n=n; this.side=side; this.R=R;
            this.linePen=linePen;
            this.dotPen=dotPen;
            this.idPen=idPen;
            makeCycle();
            draw();
        }
    } 
\end{asydef}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
size(8cm);
cycloQuad(linePen=darkblue+1.2bp,idPen=deepred);
\end{asy}

\begin{asy}
size(9cm);
cycloQuad(n=7,side=1.6,R=17,linePen=orange+1.4bp, idPen=blue,dotPen=red+1bp);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```